# SELECT pgr_nodeNetwork query fails

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pgrouting

I am working on windows, and have enabled the extension postgis, pgrouting on database. I have postgreSQL 9.4 installed and i am using the data from boundless workshop (http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/tutorial-routing/).

```
SELECT pgr_nodeNetwork('edges',0.001,'geom','gid','noded')
```

when I run this query, it runs about 1minute and after that time it results in `FAIL`. How can I solve this issue? My pgr_createTopology query has been successfully run.

```
NOTICE:  PROCESSING:
NOTICE:  pgr_nodeNetwork('edges',0.001,'geom','gid','noded')
NOTICE:  Performing checks, pelase wait .....
NOTICE:  Processing, pelase wait .....
ERROR:  line_locate_point: 1st arg isnt a line
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "create temp table inter_loc on commit drop as ( select * from (
        (select l1id, l2id, st_linelocatepoint(line,source) as locus from intergeom)
         union
        (select l1id, l2id, st_linelocatepoint(line,target) as locus from intergeom)) as foo
        where locus<>0 and locus<>1)"
PL/pgSQL function pgr_nodenetwork(text,double precision,text,text,text) line 184 at EXECUTE statement
********** Error **********

ERROR: line_locate_point: 1st arg isnt a line
SQL state: XX000
Context: SQL statement "create temp table inter_loc on commit drop as ( select * from (
        (select l1id, l2id, st_linelocatepoint(line,source) as locus from intergeom)
         union
        (select l1id, l2id, st_linelocatepoint(line,target) as locus from intergeom)) as foo
        where locus<>0 and locus<>1)"
PL/pgSQL function pgr_nodenetwork(text,double precision,text,text,text) line 184 at EXECUTE statement
```

Comment: This looks like a pgrouting internal error. Perhaps it is best to report this to the developers.

Comment: I created an issue for this on pgrouting
https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/issues/335

Comment: Thank you i am looking forward for the answer !

Comment: In the Github issue another user reported the same problem. The cause there was a "multilinesting" geometry.

Comment: I figured out that this problem can be solved if you import data into you database from shapefile using ogr2ogr..

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue in my project and I was stuck on it for hours trying to figure out what was causing it AND how to fix it. I will describe my situation and how I fixed it so hopefully, it helps someone else in the future.

I am using [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) to import a Shapefile into my database and I was using the `-nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI` as one of my arguments during my import; this caused my geometries to be imported as MultiLineStrings.

From the behavior I've observed and [what others have mentioned](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/116444) (and [more people](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/95263)), the [`pgr_nodeNetwork()`](https://docs.pgrouting.org/3.2/en/pgr_nodeNetwork.html) function does not play nicely with MutliLineStrings.

Since MultiLineStrings won't work for routing, I took the [SQL from dkastl's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/116444) and ran it on my data to see if I actually **needed** MultiLineStrings or if I could just work with LineStrings.

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(
        CASE WHEN ST_NumGeometries(geom) > 1 THEN 1 END
    ) AS multi,
    COUNT(geom) AS total
FROM network_nodes;
```

After running that, I found that I had zero need for MultiLineStrings so I reimported my Shapefile with ogr2ogr using `-nlt LINESTRING` instead and then was able to run `pgr_nodeNetwork()` without problems.